# Passing exception to slot while emitting signal

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I have to pass what exception occured in one function to a slot inside a different class.

```
_qObject = QtCore.QObject()

except Exception, ex:
    QtCore.QObject.emit(_qObject, QtCore.SIGNAL("error_occured"))
```

I want to pass ex to class that has

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(_qObject, QtCore.SIGNAL("error_occured"), self.__errorOccured)
```

This is my case

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication

has_error = pyqtSignal(Exception)

class SomeOtherClass(QWidget):

    # this is my UI class
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SomeOtherClass, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialise the Class and connect signal to slot
        has_error.connect(self.thrown_error)


    @pyqtSlot(Exception)
    def thrown_error(self, my_err):
        #Do Stuff with the Exception
        print(type(my_err), my_err)
        self.close()


def makeError():
    try:
        print 1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError, ze:
        has_error.emit(ze)

app = QApplication([])
SomeOtherClass()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below code for example:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication
import sys    

class SomeClass(QWidget):
    # Declare a new signal - passes Exception
    has_error = pyqtSignal(Exception)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SomeClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run_something(self):
        #Force an Error
        try:
            1 / 0
        except ZeroDivisionError as ze:
            #Emit the Signal
            self.has_error.emit(ze)


class SomeOtherClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SomeOtherClass, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialise the Class and connect signal to slot
        class1 = SomeClass()
        class1.has_error.connect(self.thrown_error)
        class1.run_something()

    @pyqtSlot(Exception)
    def thrown_error(self, my_err):
        #Do Stuff with the Exception
        print(type(my_err), my_err)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
SomeOtherClass()
```

See [the new way](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) to connect signals to slots

Comment: what does `@pyqtSlot(Exception)` do above `thrown_error(...)` method

Comment: `@pyqtSlot()` is a decorator and `Exception` is the type. It declares this method as a slot so that Qt wont bind it twice. Please see the documentation I linked at the bottom of my example.

Comment: also i do not have `SomeClass()` in my case its just a function at module level.

Comment: In that case you don't need the signal/slots mechanism. just call `SomeClass.some_method(my_err)` in your `try...except` block

Comment: Or put a `class` around your function and use the example above.

Comment: I have update the post to show what my case is... I think I cannot call this like you have suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56559/discussion-between-san-and-shadow9043).

Answer (score 0):

How Shadow9043 suggested is also right but in comments things got twisted but this is what I found the correct and simplistic approach.

Long Story in Short!!!

```
except Exception, ex:
    QtCore.QObject.emit(_qObject, QtCore.SIGNAL("error_occured"), str(ex))
```

and in the class where I connect this exception

i will take this ex string as argument

```
def __errorOccured(self, exStr):
    print exStr
```

Here is how I have it working, if anyone has got better suggestion in how I achieved it please comment.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys

_qObject = QtCore.QObject()


class SomeOtherClass(QWidget):

    # this is my UI class

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SomeOtherClass, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialise the Class and connect signal to slot
        QtCore.QObject.connect(_qObject, QtCore.SIGNAL("error_occured"), self.thrown_error)


    def thrown_error(self, my_err):
        #Do Stuff with the Exception
        print(type(my_err), my_err)


def makeError():
    try:
        print 1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError, ex:
        QtCore.QObject.emit(_qObject, QtCore.SIGNAL("error_occured"), str(ex))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = SomeOtherClass()
makeError()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```